# Spring form data is not received in controller with mustache

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, post, mustache

I'm using a simple Spring form with mustache. However the data is not received in Spring controller. `login.getId(), login.getPass()` are always received as null in controller. Any clues if something have to be fixed in template or controller?

My template and controller code as below.

```
<form class="form-signin" id="loginForm" action="{{{appCtxt}}}/login" method="post">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="{{id}}" id="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="{{pass}}" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private LoginService loginService;

    @Autowired
    public void setLoginService(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView();
        model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
        result.addObject("resources", request.getContextPath() + "/resources");
        result.addObject("appCtxt", request.getContextPath());
//      return "redirect:/users";
        result.setViewName("home");
        return result;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(Login login, HttpServletRequest request){
        boolean status = loginService.verifyLogin(login.getId(), login.getPass());
        if(status == true) {
            return "redirect:/users";
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `name="{{pass}}"` you can use `name="pass"` assuming you Login class contains a field with the very same name. Another thing is that you need '@ModelAttribute' annotation near the Login parameter.

For easier understanding how it works, please consider following example:

**Student.java**

```
package me.disper.model;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

**student.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create new student</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="student" action="add" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
        Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyMustacheController.java**

```
package me.disper;

import me.disper.model.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyMustacheController {

    @GetMapping("/student")
    public ModelAndView createStudent(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("student", "student", new Student());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ModelAndView addStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("created", "student", student);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

**created.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Student created</title>
</head>
<body>
{{#student}}
Hello {{name}} {{surname}}
{{/student}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After searching a lot on the internet, this was the best explanation that I could find for posting form data with mustache.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following tutorial: [A guide to forms in Spring MVC](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial). There are some helpful hints like `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: I can use ModelAttribute if i'm using a JSP (I can use it in Controller). In my case, i'm on html (template).